# How to append multiple columns of one DF into one column of another DF effectivly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am searching for an effective way to get multiple columns of one Dataframe into one column of another Dataframe.
I managed to do this by getting the columnnames of the original DF, taking the series of each column and appending these columns one-by-one to an empty list.

```
column_names = []
column_names.append(df.columns.values.tolist())

for col in df[column_names[0]]:
        for element in series:
            H_list.append(element)

df_new =pd.DataFrame({"NewColumn": column_names})
```

This feels really uneffective and I bet there is a more pythonic way to do this.

Comment: [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) is a reasonable way to go here, especially if you care about which column each datum came from.

Comment: y melt works perfectly here aswell, Thanks a lot @Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DataFrame.stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [DataFrame.Transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

**Here is an example:**

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['col1']=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
df['col2']=[7,8,9,10,11,12]
print(df)

   col1  col2
0     1     7
1     2     8
2     3     9
3     4     10
4     5     11
5     6     12
```

---

```
df2=pd.DataFrame()
df2['col1']=[11,12,13,14,15,16,11,12,13,14,15,16]
print(df2)


    col1
0     11
1     12
2     13
3     14
4     15
5     16
6     11
7     12
8     13
9     14
10    15
11    16
```

---

```
my_stack_df=df.T.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
df2['col2']=my_stack_df
print(df2)



    col1  col2
0     11     1
1     12     2
2     13     3
3     14     4
4     15     5
5     16     6
6     11     7
7     12     8
8     13     9
9     14     10
10    15     11
11    16     12
```

Comment: but I think `.melt()` is even more elegant, and just dropping the variable-column don't you think?